# I want to create an APEX report or table that has 2 sheets on the same report and extract it as 2 sheets in the same excel

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I want to create an APEX report or table that has 2 sheets on the same report and extract it as 2 sheets in the same excel , how to make something like that as in detailes as i am new to apex

i have tried to make it but it doesn't work

Comment: "i have tried to make it but it doesn't work" is not a constructive comment and it does not tell us what you have tried and what the error was when it didn't work. Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with details of your current attempt at a solution and the issues/errors with your solution and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Apex has a component called "Region Display Selector". That is a native component that allows regions on the same page to be shown/hidden with a tab. [Here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/region-display-selector) is an example in the Universal Theme. So for your requirement, a simple solution is to create 3 regions

1. Region 1: Type "Region Display Selector"
2. Region 2 and 3: Type: (depending on your requirments) Classic Report/Interactive Report/Interactive Grid with attribute Advanced > Region Display Selector: "On"